# Construct an SQL query to populate one table using data from another

Tags: sql, ms-access

This is a challenge for someone experienced with SQL (MS-Access in this case)

I have 2 tables: `holdings` and `valuations`.

---

**`holdings`** contains all the assets a particular account holds on a given date and their respective values. These are the fields:

`id`{primary key/auto-inc}, `accountid` {int}, `holdingdate` {date}, `holdingid` {int}, `holdingvalue` {double}

**`valuations`** contains the sum of the holdings of a particular account on a given date. These are the fields:

`id`{primary key/auto-inc}, `accountid` {int}, `valuationdate` {date}, `valuation` {double}.

---

Post Jan 2012, for every `valuation` in the `valuations` table I have a corresponding collection of holdings in the `holdings` table whose summed value = the valuation.

Prior to this date I only have the valuations, no holdings.

---

For example in `valuations` I would have a record like so:

```
id  |  accountid  |  valuationdate  |  valuation
------------------------------------------------
56  |  12345      |  2013-03-31     |  2000000
```

Correspondingly I would have these holdings (which add up to `valuation` for this account on this date:

```
id  |  accountid  |  holdingdate  |  holdingid  |  holdingvalue
---------------------------------------------------------------
250 |  12345      |  2013-03-31   |  16         |  1000000
251 |  12345      |  2013-03-31   |  38         |  500000
252 |  12345      |  2013-03-31   |  27         |  500000
```

As mentioned above, there are some cases where I only have the record in the `valuations` table, I have no corresponding holdings.

---

In order to simplify/optimize my database structure I want to eliminate the `valuations` table as it is essentially duplicating information that should be present in the `holdings` table by simply summing the assets for an account on a given date. In order to obtain a client's valuation going forward I can simply sum their holdings for a given date, negating the need for the `valuations` table completely.

My goal is to populate the `holdings` table with the data from `valuations` for dates where it doesn't exist.

Essentially, if no holdings exist for an account number/valuation date combination then insert a dummy holding (`holdingid = 999`) to the holdings table for that account number/valuation date equal to the valuation on that date.

Is it possible to construct an SQL query to achieve the above?

Comment: can you be more clearer in the date part

Comment: I have added an example case by demonstrating some `holdings` that correspond with a `valuation` record. Does this clarify what you're unsure about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either one of these should work:

```
insert into holdings (accountid, holdingdate, holdingid, holdingvalue) 
select v.accountid, v.valuationdate, 999, v.valuation
from valuations v
left join holdings h on h.accountid=v.accountid and h.holdingdate=v.valuationdate
where h.holdingdate is null 

EDIT: Corrected the second version to use a correlated WHERE clause.

insert into holdings (accountid, holdingdate, holdingid, holdingvalue) 
select v.accountid, v.valuationdate, 999, v.valuation 
from valuations v
where v.valuationdate not in (select distinct holdingdate from holdings where accountid=v.accountid)
```

Comment: should it be `INSERT INTO` rather than just `INSERT`?

Comment: And does the `v.column` get allowed by doing `valuation v`? I.e. gives you a shorthand name?

Comment: @harryg Yes. You can use aliases this way, but they're really not needed, I just use aliases out of habit to make queries shorter.

Comment: OK, here goes, about to run it.

Comment: @harryg Make a copy of the DB before you run it!

Comment: @harryg I've updated the second version as it produced incorrect results. I do however think that the first version is better.

Comment: Yup, made a backup beforehand. Ran the first and it looks like it worked. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use WHERE NOT IN based on the date.

```
INSERT INTO holdings
(accountid, holdingdate, holdingid, holdingvalue)
SELECT accountid, valuationdate, NULL, valuation 
FROM valuations
WHERE valuationdate NOT IN (
  SELECT holdingdate 
  FROM holdings
)
```

I don't know if you still need both an Id column and a holdingid column. You'll have to decide what to do with those.